# Azure commands not working in ISE but do in PS shell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to my Azure AD with my companies O365 account.  When I run the commands in the PS shell, works great.  But trying to make a ps1 script file, commands fail in ISE.  Code and errors below:

Code:

```
$managedcred = get-storedcredential -Target o365

connect-azuread -credential $managedcred
```

Error:

> Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.: AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password.
>   Trace ID: 3bbf3cba-61c3-45c5-a19f-60973b7c2700
>   Correlation ID: 14599060-8bb3-4fce-afda-621efc3660ed
>   Timestamp: 2019-10-03 16:05:03Z
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -Credential $managedcred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AadAuthenticationFailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

---

> Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -Credential $managedcred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AggregateException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

---

> Connect-AzureAD : AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password.
>   Trace ID: 3bbf3cba-61c3-45c5-a19f-60973b7c2700
>   Correlation ID: 14599060-8bb3-4fce-afda-621efc3660ed
>   Timestamp: 2019-10-03 16:05:03Z
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -Credential $managedcred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AdalServiceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

---

> Connect-AzureAD : Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest).
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -Credential $managedcred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], HttpRequestException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

---

> Connect-AzureAD : {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password.\r\nTrace ID: 
>   3bbf3cba-61c3-45c5-a19f-60973b7c2700\r\nCorrelation ID: 14599060-8bb3-4fce-afda-621efc3660ed\r\nTimestamp: 2019-10-03 
>   16:05:03Z","error_codes":[50126],"timestamp":"2019-10-03 16:05:03Z","trace_id":"3bbf3cba-61c3-45c5-a19f-60973b7c2700","correlation_id":"14599060-8bb3-4fce-afda-621efc366
>   0ed","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50126"}: Unknown error
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -Credential $managedcred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AdalException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

---

> Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.: AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password.
>   Trace ID: 3bbf3cba-61c3-45c5-a19f-60973b7c2700
>   Correlation ID: 14599060-8bb3-4fce-afda-621efc3660ed
>   Timestamp: 2019-10-03 16:05:03Z
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -Credential $managedcred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AadAuthenticationFailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadAuthenticationFailedException,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

So it appears that the first command works fine, but the connect fails.

Comment: Looks like your credentials used to connect were incorrect? Do you any way to confirm that what you're retrieving is correct?

Comment: I do not know how to make sure they are pulled correctly.  However I am using the exact same two commands in the ISE and the CLI.  CLI works, ISE fails

Comment: UPDATE: Now it is not working in either platform, ISE or CLI

Answer (score 0):

According to error message, you do not use the correct username and password to connect Azure AD. Please use the following command to check it.

```
 Get-StoredCredential -Target O365 -AsCredentialObject
```

[image]

Besides, according to my understanding, you want to connect Azure AD without a prompt. You also can use the following command:

```
$name = ""
$password = ""
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($name, $secpasswd)
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $mycreds
```

## Update

According to research, app password is used to complete MFA with the clients which do not support modern authentication, such as outlook. For more details, please refer to https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/12409/microsoft-account-app-passwords-and-two-step-verification. So we cannot use app password to connect Azure AD in PowerShell ISE.

According to the situation, I suggest you use service principal to connect Azure AD. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0.

Comment: I did the command you gave to check, the creds look correct.  I am using an "app password" as I have two factor auth on my account.  The hard coded section gives the same error, bad user and pass

Comment: @TheMattMan0425 Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concern, could you please accept the answer? It may help more people.

Comment: I guess I accept.  I accept that this won't work the way I wish it.